# PHP echo block behavior

Tags: php, html, mysql, echo

```
for($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j) 
{
    $result->data_seek($j);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
echo <<<_END
    <pre>
    Author: $row[0]
    Title: $row[1]
    Type: $row[2]
    Year: $row[3]
    ISBN: $row[4]
    </pre>
_END;
}
```

There are two things I've encountered in using `echo` for block of texts and I'm a bit stumped in coming up with an explanation.

1. Any indentation of the `echo` block will cause the webpage to crash.
2. If I change the `fetch_array` type to either `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, or `MYSQLI_BOTH`, associative calls such as `$row['author']` cause the page to crash. Whereas using single-line calls to `echo` while accessing `$row` are working fine.

Comment: The indentation only pertains the closing [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) marker `_END;`. And string interpolation in double quoted / heredoc context either needs literal `"$row[key]"` or [complex `"${row['key']}"` syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) for quoted keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. PHP [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)'s closing identifier should not indented. Here is warning paragraph from the manual.

> **Warning** It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system.

2. Inside heredoc, array keys either should not be quoted, or quoted inside `${}` notation.

   ```
   $array[key] // works (the only place you do not quote string keys in PHP)
   ${array["key"]} // works
   $array["key"] // doesn't work
   ```